# Error when mixing C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I would like to create Win32 application with GUI in cpp-files and main logic in c-files. Things are ok until c-function, called within c++ code with CreateThread, for example open COM port. I got IDE hanging in C++ Builder and error in CodeBlocks+GCC.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't say much about the problem, I'll take a guess:

Maybe your C headers don't have an `extern "C" { ... }`?

[C++ FAQ lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html) gives more details.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks. Now all is working fine. My mistake was that I tied C and C++ code by writing in cpp-file this lines:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "Klnmain.c"
}
```

When I had created h-file with declaration of exported from C to C++ C-functions and variables, common for c-files and cpp-files, and had written

```
extern "C" {
    #include "Klnmain.h"
}
```

in cpp-files, problems have dissappeared. :-)